# Angular js - ng-model in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

Different 'ng-model name' in ng repeat - Possible?

```
<div  ng-repeat="todo in todos">
   <input type="text" ng-model="tag">  
   <button type="submit"ng-click="addTodo(todo._id)">Add</button>
</div>
```

In this case,  there are some  repeat todo item (based on todos json data) will show on frontend

My Problem:  What i type on any input field  , all input field showing same data

I need different ng-model name on each input field , I guess like this  `ng-model="tag($index)"`

Comment: Can you add code of your controller and show how you store tags and todos?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible like below

```
<div  ng-repeat="todo in todos">
   <input type="text" ng-model="tag[todo]">  <--todo.key-->
   <button type="submit"ng-click="addTodo(todo._id)">Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could place the newly created model inside tag array by its `$index`, while declaring model inside the `tag` you should use array notation `[]` instead of `()`

```
ng-model="tag($index)"
```

should be

```
ng-model="tag[$index]"
```

**Markup**

```
<div  ng-repeat="todo in todos">
   <input type="text" ng-model="tag[$index]">  
   <button type="submit"ng-click="addTodo(todo._id)">Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="todo.tag">
```